# Target type of lambda conversion must be an interface for ConnectionHolder - SpringBoot Java

Tags: java

1. I am new to SpringBoot and am trying to test my repository so I need to connect to the Datasource. I am using JDBC. Please see my sample code method for reference
2. I am using intellij and the error is 'Target type of lambda conversion must be an interface.
3. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

```
 public ConnectionHolder getConnectionHolder() {
      // return a function that retrieves a connection from our data source
      return () -> dataSource.getConnection();
   }
```

Comment: [tag:java] !== [tag:javascript], not even close

Comment: ops. made a mistake in there

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Spring-boot and I am using [spring data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa) for database and it's super flexible and easy to implement.

Also Check : https://spring.io/projects/spring-data

Answer (score 0):

To those reading this problem, the solution lies with the import statement. Make sure you use this import statement:
import com.github.database.rider.core.api.connection.ConnectionHolder;

The reason for the error is because only functional interfaces can use lambda expressions. And the interfaces must contain only one abstract method.

The reason for the error is because I previously imported ConnectionHolder from a different package which was not a functional interace.

The maven dependency for rider or for the import statement, is as follows:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.database-rider</groupId>
            <artifactId>rider-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>
```